# Fail Jenkins Pipeline when required environment variable is empty

Tags: jenkins, cicd

I am currently writing a Jenkins-Pipeline and have some URLs which I want to set via env-Variables.
Those URLs are required and I do not want to run stages conditionally. The stages need always to run, so I need to make sure the variables are given. Is there any way to directly fail the pipeline if the variables are missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        // Declare your environment variables
        URLS = '' 
    }
    stages {
        stage('Verify URLS') {
            steps {
                script {
                    if (!env.URLS) {
                        error('Missing URLS variable')
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also set `currentBuild.result` to `'FAILURE'`

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        URLS = '' 
    }
   stages {
       stage('Verify URLS') {
           steps {
               script {
                   if (!env.URLS) {
                       currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```